# Regular expression where Binary numbers have no ones and zeros follow each other directly

Tags: java, regex

Hi I'm trying to find a regular expression where a binary number has no ones and zeros follow each other directly.
This is the regular expression I have:

```
public static boolean isBin2(String bin2) {
        Pattern regexBinary2 = Pattern.compile("(01*01)*");

        Matcher matcher = regexBinary2.matcher(bin2);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

This is the String I'm using for my tests: "10101010"

The expression should check like this:

10101010 --> is allowed

10010101 --> is not allowed

But this expression always returns false even when the binary number is allowed and I can't find the cause of it. Would be nice if you could help me.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't really make sense. An asterisk means "zero or more occurrences of the preceding character"

Comment: `Pattern regexBinary2 = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*([01])\\1)[01]+");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regular expression that doesn't use look around:

```
^0?(10)*1?$
```

It says that valid input starts with an optional 0, is followed by zero or more sequences of `10`, and optionally has one more 1 at the end.

This will also match empty input. If an empty input should be rejected, then add a `\b`:

```
^\b0?(10)*1?$
```

Make sure to escape the backslash when placing this in a string literal:

```
    Pattern regexBinary2 = Pattern.compile("^\\b0?(10)*1?$");
```

Comment: Good one! The capturing group is not required...I mean, you can modify it to `^0?(?:10)*1?$`.

Comment: Using the same technique, it can also be written as `^1?(?:01)*0?$`.